Deep learning for any input the output is the same while training
when I run the code it converges to the same output regardless of the input. this also include the training inputs themself as well. the desire size of input is currently 720. I am planing to double the input size. functions to focus on is 'class Model' and 'Train' the other two function are just loading function from the database.

import array
import torch
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inFeatures = 720, out=5):
        super().__init__()
        h1= 1000
        h2 = 900
        h3 = 1000
        h4 = 900
        h5 = 1000
        h6 = 900
        h7 = 1000
        h8 = 900
        h9 = 1000
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(inFeatures, h1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(h1, h2)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(h2, h3)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(h3, h4)
        self.fc5 = nn.Linear(h4, h5)
        self.fc6 = nn.Linear(h5, h6)
        self.fc7 = nn.Linear(h6, h7)
        self.fc8 = nn.Linear(h7, h8)
        self.fc9 = nn.Linear(h8, h9)
        self.out = nn.Linear(h9, out)

    def Foward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc4(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc5(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc6(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc7(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc8(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc9(x))
        x = self.out(x)
        return x

def LoadTrainData(myDb):
    my_cursor = myDb.cursor()
    my_cursor.execute("SELECT field_input FROM all_dual")
    inputData = my_cursor.fetchall()
    newList = []
    n = 0
    for i in inputData:
        #print('----------------', i)
        newList.append(list(map(float, i[0].split(':'))))
        n = n + 1
    return np.array(newList)

def LoadExpectedValue(myDb):
    my_cursor = myDb.cursor()
    my_cursor.execute("SELECT field_output FROM all_dual")
    outputData = my_cursor.fetchall()
    outList = []
    n = 0
    for i in outputData:

        outList.append(i[0].split(':'))
        n = n + 1
    #print(np.array(outList)[:,1].astype(int))
    return (np.array(outList)[:,1].astype(int))

def Train(myDb):
    model = Model()
    X = LoadTrainData(myDb)
    y = LoadExpectedValue(myDb)
    print('X: ', X)
    print('y: ', y)
    #print(y)

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.8)
    X_train = torch.FloatTensor(X_train)
    X_test = torch.FloatTensor(X_test)
    y_train = torch.LongTensor(y_train)
    y_test = torch.LongTensor(y_test)
    print(y_test)
    print(y_train)

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=.01)
    epochs = 100
    losses = []
    n = 0
    for i in range(epochs):
        y_pred = model.Foward(X_train)
        loss = criterion(y_pred, y_train)

        #print(loss.detach())
        if n > 4:
            losses.append(loss.detach().numpy)
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print(f'Epoch: {i} and loss: {loss}')

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        n = n + 1



    with torch.no_grad():
        for i, data in enumerate(X_test):
            y_eval = model.Foward(data)

            print(f'{i + 1}.) {str(y_eval)}, {y_test[i]}, {y_eval.argmax().item()}, {len(data)}')




I attempted this with a small data size and it worked fine but with this larger data size it all converge to the same values.
